# open mp3 file javafx not working

Tags: javafx, mp3

I have the following code :

```
    final URL resource = MainApp.class.getResource(ConstantsUI.CHEMIN_AUDIO+"675.mp3");
System.out.println("--1--");        
Media hit = new Media(resource.toString()); 
System.out.println(resource.toString());        
System.out.println("--2--");    
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
System.out.println("--3--");    
mediaPlayer.play(); 
System.out.println("playiiiiing");
```

My execute code show :

```
--1--
file:/home/osboxes/workspace/Project/bin/view/resources/audios/675.mp3
--2--
```

I try with the file "675.wav" and it's working. How do work a mp3 file ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is important for you to use JavaFX to play mp3?If not one better option is JLayer (  http://javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html  ).With search you will find some examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String path = "ConstantsUI.CHEMIN_AUDIO+"675.mp3"
Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.play();
```